# Splitting a Column Using a Separator Character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is an example row of data stored in this column

```
'88922774 8785075 9417025'
```

I am trying to return all 3 separate numbers with the `' '` separator. It's also possible for there to be a 4th column in some cases.

Usually for splitting strings I would have used the following

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE([ColumnName], ' ', '.'), 1) 
PARSENAME(REPLACE([ColumnName], ' ', '.'), 2) 
PARSENAME(REPLACE([ColumnName], ' ', '.'), 3)
PARSENAME(REPLACE([ColumnName], ' ', '.'), 4)
```

However this is not returning any data for this particular table and I do not understand why that is. Because if I execute the following for example I see the expected result:

```
Select 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE('A Test Name', ' ', '.'), 1),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE('A Test Name', ' ', '.'), 2),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE('A Test Name', ' ', '.'), 3)
```

I have tried using `substring()` instead but am only able to return the first and second items from the string, but not the third.

Assistance would be appreciated.

My expected output is this: rextester.com/ACFL85345

However what I actually see is NULL values. I'm using SQL server 2005.

Comment: Don't store data like that, have one value per row.

Comment: it works..check this.. http://rextester.com/ACFL85345

Comment: is it possible that the character between the three sets of numbers is not a standard " "? Because what you are doing looks good.

Comment: Could this be because I'm on an old version of SQL server because it's definitely not working on my server?

Also how can I check what character is used, I've tried both ' ' and Char(32) but I'm still returning no data.

Comment: What would be your expected output

Comment: rextester.com/ACFL85345 

this is my expected output, however the output I am seeing is NULL for all 3

Comment: which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Do you have more spaces in your actual data? If you have even 4 spaces you will get NULL across the board because of how parsename works.

Comment: Please update your question with expected output with sample data

Comment: @vkp I'm using SQL server 2005

Comment: @user2976138 .. PARSENAME is only available starting SQL Server 2012

Comment: @user2976138: Please check my answer. It would work in sql server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is a UDF I used prior to PARSENAME()

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('88922774 8785075 9417025',' ')
```

Returns

```
Pos1        Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
88922774    8785075 9417025 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John Cappelletti',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns Table 

As

Return (
    SELECT Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(250)')
    FROM (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
```

Comment: Hi John, I'm struggling with the syntax to create this function is there a typo in there somewhere? "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf-Str-Parse-Row, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near 'A'."

Comment: @user2976138: Remove the open parenthesis in the `Return (`, it will work.

Comment: @user2976138 Sorry, I didn't paste in the final ")".  Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use CHARINDEX for finding the index of your seperator (here ' ') and with the help of SUBSTRING function you can split the string in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(50)='88922774 8785075 9417025' 

select LEFT(@val, charindex(' ', @val) - 1),
   SUBSTRING(@val, charindex(' ', @val)+1, len(@val) - CHARINDEX(' ', reverse(@val)) - charindex(' ', @val)),
       REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(@val), charindex(' ', reverse(@val)) - 1))
```

Comment: I can get the 1st and the 2nd items in this way, but not currently able to get the 3rd

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @item VARCHAR(MAX) = '88922774 8785075 9417025'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@item, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @item)) AS col1
    ,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@item, CHARINDEX(' ', @item) + 1, LEN(@ITEM)), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@item, CHARINDEX(' ', @item) + 1, LEN(@ITEM)))) AS col2
    ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@ITEM), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@ITEM)))) AS col3
```